# Different Sums On a Die - Trouble With the Solution

Tags: combinatorics, dice

How many ways are there to choose six distinct integers from ${1, 2, . . . , 11}$ such that
it is possible to attach each integer to a face of the cube where the sum of the integers
on all pairs of opposite faces are equal?

The solution: We perform casework based on the sum of the opposite faces. The minimum possible sum is $1 + 6 = 7$ and the maximum possible sum is $6 + 11 = 17$. The number of corresponding face pair possibilities for the different sums are manually computed to be $3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3$ being symmetrical about where the sum equals 12. In total, there are $2 \cdot (2 \cdot $$3 \choose 3$$ + 2 \cdot $$4 \choose 3$$ + $$5 \choose 3$$) + $$5 \choose 3$$ = 50$ possibilities $\text{(D)}$.

However, I was pretty confused by what the solution meant when it referred to corresponding face pair possibilities. Are these different rotations of the same arrangement of six integers?

Anyone who could help me understand the solution and/or solve it in a cleaner way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The natural answer (for me) would be $4{3 \choose 3}+4{4 \choose 3}+3{5 \choose 3}=50$, but perhaps you should double this to take account of [left- and right-handed dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice#Arrangement).

Comment: Could you explain how you're getting this solution? I would really like to understand for an upcoming test.

Comment: If the sum is 7 (resp 8, 9, 10, ... 17), then how many pairs sum to that value? Can you show that the answer is 3 ( resp 3, 4, 4, 5, ..., 4)?

Comment: @JohnDoe you have $3$ pairs summing to $7$ or $8$ or $16$ or $17$ and you want to pick of $3$ of them, so $4{3\choose 3}$.  Similarly $4$ pairs summing to $9$ or $10$ or $14$ or $15$, so $4{4\choose 3}$, and $5$ pairs summing to $11$ or $12$ or $13$, so $3{5\choose 3}$.  In effect what you said but slightly simpler.

Comment: Ohhhh... I guess the way to think about this problems like this in the future would be to categorize the arrangements by the sum that opposite faces add to then. Thanks!